# Bitmap from byte[] array

Tags: unity-game-engine, bitmap, arrays

I want to create a bitmap from a byte[]. My problem is that I can't use a `BitmapSource` in Unity and if I use a `MemoryStream` Unity gets an error.

I tried it with this:

```
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(512, 424);

  var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size),
  ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

  Marshal.Copy(arrayData, 0, data.Scan0, arrayData.Length);

  bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
```

It works but the Bitmap I get is the wrong way up. Can someone explain me why and got a solution for me?

Comment: You have your bitmap vertically mirrowed?

Answer (score 5):

This can be two things, perhaps combined: The [choice of coordinate system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407212(v=vs.85).aspx), and [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

There's a convention (I believe universal) to list pixels from left to right, but there's none regarding *vertical* orientation. While some programs and APIs have the Y-coordinate be zero at the bottom and increases upwards, others do the exact opposite. I don't know where you get the `byte[]` from, but some APIs allow you to configure the pixel orientation when writing, reading or using textures. Otherwise, you'll have to manually re-arrange the rows.

The same applies to endianness; ARGB sometimes means Blue is the last byte, sometimes the first.Some classes, like [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) have buit-in solutions too.

Unity uses **big-endian**, [bottom-up](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) textures. In fact, [Unity handles lots of this stuff under the hood](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PlatformDifferences.html), and has to re-order rows and flip bytes when importing bitmap files. Unity also provides methods like [LoadImage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) and [EncodeToPNG](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html) that take care of both problems.

To illustrate what happens to the `byte[]`, this sample code saves the same image in three different ways (but you need to import them as **Truecolor** to see them properly in Unity):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class CreateTexture2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Start () {

        int texWidth = 4, texHeight = 4;

        // Raw 4x4 bitmap data, in bottom-up big-endian ARGB byte order. It's transparent black for the most part.
        byte[] rawBitmap = new byte[] {

            // Red corner (bottom-left) is written first
            255,255,0,0,  0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,      0,0,0,0,
            255,0,0,255,  255,0,0,255,  255,0,0,255,  255,0,0,255
            //Blue border (top) is the last "row" of the array
        };

        // We create a Texture2D from the rawBitmap
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(texWidth, texHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(rawBitmap);
        texture.Apply();

        // 1.- We save it directly as a Unity asset (btw, this is useful if you only use it inside Unity)
        UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(texture, "Assets/TextureAsset.asset");

        // 2.- We save the texture to a file, but letting Unity handle formatting
        byte[] textureAsPNG = texture.EncodeToPNG();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/EncodedByUnity.png", textureAsPNG);

        // 3.- Rearrange the rawBitmap manually into a top-down small-endian ARGB byte order. Then write to a Bitmap, and save to disk.
        // Bonus: This permutation is it's own inverse, so it works both ways.
        byte[] rearrangedBM = new byte[rawBitmap.Length];
        for (int row = 0; row < texHeight; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < texWidth; col++)
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    rearrangedBM[row * 4 * texWidth + 4 * col + i] = rawBitmap[(texHeight - 1 - row) * 4 * texWidth + 4 * col + (3 - i)];

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(texWidth, texHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, texWidth, texHeight), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rearrangedBM, 0, data.Scan0, rearrangedBM.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
        bitmap.Save(Application.dataPath + "/SavedBitmap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```